# gulp extname on Angularjs2 files with two dots

Tags: gulp, angular, gulp-rename

Below gulp rename task works good for angularjs2 ts files with one dot, such as appcomponent.ts. However, if the file name has two dots like login.service.ts, gulp extname is confused and will take whatever after the first dot as the extension. Any idea how to let extname know the extension is after the last dot?

```
gulp.task('ts', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(rename({
      extname: ''
    }))
    .pipe(traceur({
      modules: 'instantiate',
      moduleName: true,
      annotations: true,
      types: true,
      memberVariables: true
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      extname: '.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

Comment: If this question is about Angular2 it shouldn't have the [tag:angularjs] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gulp-rename` **does** replace only the extension after the last dot. It uses `path.extname()` internally about which the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_p) states:

> Return the extension of the path, from the last '.' to end of string in the last portion of the path

Your problem are these three lines:

```
.pipe(rename({
  extname: ''
}))
```

Here you remove the `.ts` extension, so when you finally get to `rename({extname: '.js'}` the extension of your file is actually `.service`. Drop those three lines and your renaming works.